# Magento 2.2.3 - Full text filter not working for sales order grid

Tags: sales-order, filter, magento2.2.3

The full-text search filter is not working for `sales order grid`. Other filters are working correctly for sales order grid.

[image]

Comment: check sales_order_grid table and make sure you have full text indexes for increment_id

Comment: Thanks, I have added and it's working.

Comment: Your welcome :), Let me add this as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check sales_order_grid table and make sure that you have full text index for increment_id field. If there is not any index for increment_id you need to add using below script.

```
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.4', '<')) {

        $table = $setup->getTable('sales_order_grid');

        $setup->getConnection()
            ->addIndex(
                $table,
                $setup->getIdxName(
                    $table,
                    ['increment_id'],
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT
                ),
                ['increment_id'],
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT
            )
        ;
    }
```

You need to do this using UpgradeDta\Schema.